# Passing comma delimited parameter to stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have fields in mytable tab1:

```
col1     | col2     | id
--------------------------
1,2,3    | 2,3,4,5  | a1
6,7,8,9  | 2,9,11   | a2
```

i want to pass this fields to my stored procedure  input like `where col1 in ('1,2') and col2 in ('3,4');`

but it is not working ..

Comment: Can you post your stored procedure?

Comment: And show desired result.

Comment: the `IN` statement can only work with sets of values. These sets can be obtained as a result of select query (or subquery) like `... WHERE col1 IN (SELECT * FROM ...)` or as a result of input query compilation `... WHERE col1 IN (1, 2, 3 ...)`. It won't work like `... WHERE col1 IN col2`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tab1 t 
 WHERE 1 IN (t.col1) AND 2 IN (t.col1) ...
  AND 3 IN (t.col2) AND 4 IN (t.col2) ...
```

You would need to build up your query based on the inputs to your stored procedure, but otherwise this should work for you. Post your current proc?

**EDIT**

The `find_in_set` function will also work for you, but you will still have to split your inputs and call it once per number passed to the proc (i.e. the first parameter to `FIND_IN_SET` cannot be a comma separated list). Reference here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set